# Jasmine: testing if API is called using HttpTestingController

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running unit test for angular app, upon clicking button, API is called , I am testing if this API is called or not and also request method using HttpTestingController!I am using jasmine.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="name">Customer Number</label>
   <input type="text" id="accountid" class="form-control col-sm-3" [(ngModel)]="record.accountid" (change)="daemonChanged(0)" name="accountid" required>
   <button id="loadbtn" (click)="loadCustomer()" class="col-sm-3 btn">Load</button>
 </div>
```

In my spec file

```
//tried both the ways to trigger click event it doesn't work
loadButton.triggerEventHandler('click',null);
loadButton.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
fixture.detectChanges();
let dummyResponse ={"status":"SUCCESS","data":{}}; 
let req2 = _HttpTestingController.expectOne('/api/accounts');//fails here
expect(req2.request.method).toBe("POST"); 

loadCustomer () {
this.http.post('/api/accounts', this.record) //function indeed calls this API!!!
.subscribe(res => {
..some logic...
});
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Though the API is called :    test fails here                                                                                  let req2 = _HttpTestingController.expectOne('/api/accounts');//fails here
expect(req2.request.method).toBe("POST");

Comment: Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: /api/accounts", found none. Though I am able to click on load button and call this API manually but I want to stimulate using test

Comment: I had set condition to call API only if certain field was not null or empty , so the API was not getting called at all, thanks :)